# Update query for value replace from column1 to column2 in single table

Tags: mysql

I want to update the Resolved time as Created time and status = resolved for the list of ids.

```
+-------+---------------------+---------------------+--------+
| id    | created             | Resolved            | Status |
+-------+---------------------+---------------------+--------+
| 15367 | 2012-07-11 21:15:05 | 1970-01-01 00:00:00 | new    |
| 15370 | 2012-07-11 21:21:12 | 1970-01-01 00:00:00 | new    |
| 15374 | 2012-07-11 21:27:28 | 1970-01-01 00:00:00 | new    |
| 15377 | 2012-07-11 21:31:06 | 1970-01-01 00:00:00 | new    |
+-------+---------------------+---------------------+--------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query,

update table_name set Resolved = created,status= 'resolved'  WHERE id in (15367,15370,15374 ,15377)

Answer (score 2):

Any problem with [`UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html) query?

```
UPDATE myTable SET Resolved = Created, Status = 'Resolved' 
WHERE ID IN (15367,15370,15374 ,15377)
```

## [*See this SQLFiddle*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/14729/1)